# Finding multiple radio buttons of the same name in Django webtest

Tags: django, forms, beautifulsoup, webtest

I'm writing some web tests with the Django webtest where I'm trying to set one radio button in a pair of radio buttons to be checked. Naturally, they both have the same `name` attribute value.

Using `pdb`, and assuming I have a `form` variable whose type is `webtest.forms.Form`, here's what I see if I type `form.html`, i.e. what Webtest has been handed by beautifulsoup (only part of it, but the relevant part).

```
<input name="is_external" type="radio" value="False"/>
<input name="is_external" type="radio" value="True"/>
```

Normally to select a specific input element which shares a name with other input elements I'd do something like `form.get('is_external', index=1)` which would in this example select the `input` whose value is `True`.

However, when I do this I'm merely given the error message:

`*** IndexError: list index out of range`.

`form.get('is_external')` on its own will only give me the first one. I've checked the docs and they are sadly [lacking when it comes to radio buttons](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webtest/en/latest/forms.html#radio).

Am I missing something? I've used this method with `type="checkbox"` elements before and I've had no problems.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague gave me some information that led to figuring out an answer.

It turns out that according to Webtest, `Radio` buttons are seen as a single item in the `Form` API. So in order to select another one, you need to use:

```
form['is_external'].select('True')
```

That way, the second input in my example is given `checked="checked"`. So it's not possible to select a specific radio button in the Webtest `Form` class.

Comment: This is generally the case with radio buttons with the same name - particularly as users can only select a single radio button at a time.  Better to think of them as being a different way of displaying a select.

Comment: Thanks John! I can see it now, it does make sense but I guess I thought it'd have a similar API to a checkbox and webtest would just unselect any radio button that had the same name. Cheers for the input :)